# .NET Interactive Notebooks: How do I overwrite a nuget package version?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, f#-interactive

I'm using [.NET notebooks for VSCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.dotnet-interactive-vscode). Current version: v1.0.2419011

I'm trying to experiment with a nuget package

I first loaded the package like

```fs
#r "nuget: Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.MSBuild"
```

Then I realized I needed a preview version

```fs
#r "nuget: Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.MSBuild, 4.0.0-3.final"
```

However, the notebook won't let me change versions of the package. It errors with

> Error: Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.MSBuild version 4.0.0-1.final cannot be added because version 3.11.0 was added previously.

I don't see any options for clearing the packages or forcing an overwrite. How do I change package versions after previously loading a different version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out the same question got asked in the project's Github issues, [#342](https://github.com/dotnet/interactive/issues/342#issuecomment-612485767).

The answer is to restart the notebook kernel. Restarting the kernel is slightly out of the way. It can be run through the command search (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd>)

[image]